# importing ColorThief doesn't work and messes up code

Tags: javascript, color-thief

I tried to import ColorThief into my code but I get an error saying

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I don't know what to do since I just copied the import statement on the ColorThief website, and I downloaded the node-module thing so the path is correct.

In addition I found out that the import statement causes another error. It causes my setBio function to be "declared but never read" but I used it in my HTML file like this:

`<button onClick=setBio()>Search</button>`

The error disappears and everything works (all the features I implemented before trying to implement a color thief feature) once I comment out the import statement.

Here's a condensed version of what's in my JS file:

```
import ColorThief from './node_modules/colorthief/dist/color-thief.mjs'

let setBio = async () =>
{
    let input = document.getElementById("input");
    let pokemon = input.value.toLowerCase();
    input.value = ""

    let display = document.getElementById("name");
    display.innerHTML = await getName(pokemon);

    let pic = document.getElementById("img");
    pic.src = await getPic(pokemon);
    setBGColor();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am new so I apologize if it's something stupid

Comment: [Are you setting the type of your main script to "module"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)?

Comment: @Andy yes. I have it in my head element like this:
`<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>`